# How can I parse this text file to get the first group of digits on each line?

Tags: perl

I got a text file of this kind

```
INFO [main] (porter.java:100) - Added record 7147  read from file: 1484301                 
INFO [main] (porter.java:100) - Added record 7148  read from file: 1484302   
INFO [main] (porter.java:100) - Added record 17147 read from file: 1484303  
INFO [main] (porter.java:100) - Added record 76148 read from file: 1484333  
INFO [main] (porter.java:100) - Added record 148   read from file: 1484342
```

How can I parse this, getting the first digits in this case like

```
7147
7148
17147
76148
148
```

Comment: You didn't bother to type command *perldoc perlre*, did you. I'm going to register WouldYouWriteThatCodeForMe.com and make trillions $$$.

Comment: First, you read _Learning Perl_, then you type out the solution. Easy peasy. :)

Comment: @hlynur From the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq): “Be nice … We're all here to learn together. Be tolerant of others who may not know everything you know.”

Comment: @Greg Bacon So generous and right you are. What was that story about giving man a fishing rod instead of fish? --- SO should teach people, not give them ready solutions only and keep them stupid (or shouldn't it?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regex would work nicely.  Depending on what else is in the file you could get away with

```
while (<>) {
    next unless my ($n) = /Added record ([0-9]+)/;
    print "$n\n";
}
```

Comment: `if ( defined $n ) { print "$n\n" }`

Comment: my $string = "INFO [main] (porter.java:100) - Added record 7147  read from file: 1484301"; How can i get 7147 from this.Sorry chris i'm new to perl and im learning.

Comment: `my ($n) = $string =~ /Added record ([0-9]+)/;`  Read [`perldoc perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html).

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking of the following pattern for the regex:

```
my ($n) = /record ([0-9]+)/;
```

This might capture lines containing 
Deleted record |
Appended record |
Changed record |
etc. etc..

Answer (score 0):

From the shell:

```
perl -wlane'print $F[6]' <infile >outfile
```

or

```
cut -d ' ' -f 7 <infile >outfile
```